# Getting "Unable to connect to a repository" error in CodePlex with TortoiseSVN

Tags: visual-studio-2010, svn, open-source, tortoisesvn, codeplex

I just created a project over at codeplex and tried committing the sourcecode (so my project can be available publicly).

TortoiseSVN just doesn't work with CodePlex anymore it seems.  And codeplex doesn't let you change source uploading options without contacting them first.

The errors in get when I try to checkout are:

```
Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'http://onthefly.codeplex.com'
The OPTIONS request returned invalid XML in the response: XML parse error at
line 1: no element found (https://onthefly.svn.codeplex.com/svn)
```

and

```
OPTIONS of 'http://onthefly.codeplex.com': could not connect to server
```

I tried the repo-browser just now and it still won't work.

Here's a screenshot of one of the errors:

[image]

Why are these errors happening?

Comment: Are you certain the URL you are using is correct?

Comment: Well i'm using the url that codeplex says to use

Comment: @JamesKent - [This project is not yet published](https://onthefly.codeplex.com/), I didn't see this error on published project, and you can try to use correct auth-data with any CLI-command  (if don't want publish), because error translated as "authettication issue happened"

Comment: I can't publish my project yet because I haven't committed my source code/uploaded source code - and I'm trying to do that but that damn thing just doesn't work. I have no idea how to use CLI-command - what's that all about?

Comment: I've got it working. Follow instructions on this page: http://codeplex.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Using%20TortoiseHG%20with%20CodePlex if you're having these same issues.

Comment: Are you behind a proxy? Some proxies filter svn-specific HTTP-verbs out.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I've got it working. Follow instructions on [this](http://codeplex.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Using%20TortoiseHG%20with%20CodePlex) page if you're having these same issues.

Comment: Can you tell me what exactly you did, there is a lot on that linked tutorial page.

Answer (score 2):

You're not using the correct URL for repo.  The correct URL is:

`https://<projectname>.svn.codeplex.com/svn`

Comment: Yah, I've tried that url too, many times, in every single imaginable way - and it throws errors at my face. I just updated my question to include the error I am getting :)