# Xcode to TFS via SVNBridge

Tags: xcode, svn, tfs, tfvc, svnbridge

I heard that SVNBridge has 2 products: Client and Server but I have to use SVNBridge Server if I want to access from MAC? Is that true?

Is there any limitation/stability issue using SVNBridge Server from Xcode to connect to TFS?

I am looking for basic support basically: check in/check out/comment/history/show changes?

Comment: Have you considered looking into git-tf to clone a local Git repository of your Team Foundation Version Control, and then connect to that repository via Xcode?
http://gittf.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0):

Don't use [svnbridge](https://svnbridge.codeplex.com).

1. It's abandonware.  It hasn't been updated since September 2013.
2. It [doesn't work with new svn clients](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13074239/getting-unable-to-connect-to-a-repository-error-in-codeplex-with-tortoisesvn).  This is important to point out, lest you think that you could still use it, despite having not been updated in two years.
3. Assuming that you were able to find a compatible svn client (probably not the one included with Xcode), it's challenging to set up correctly.  It was built for adding svn compatibility to CodePlex, first and foremost, and getting it setup for your installation *particularly in client mode* is fraught with peril.  And, of course, there's not an active community, so there's nobody to ask questions to - it's just you alone in a debugger.
4. If you did manage to get it set up, and did manage to find a compatible svn client...  it should actually give you the basics that you're asking for (view history, check out, check in), but things like branching and merging are problematic.

Use a git <-> TFS translation layer like [git-tf](https://gittf.codeplex.com).  This has some of the same limitations (things like branching and merging are problematic, and it's basically abandonware), but it at least is a modern take on the SVNBridge problem.

Or you can simply use the native TFVC client for Mac OS X, [Team Explorer Everywhere](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=47727), which offers a cross-platform command-line client.  Regrettably, though, there is no integration directly into Xcode for TFVC, so you will have to use the command-line.